# Can I make Vue.js keep-alive work across sites?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli

I'm using the `<keep-alive>` tag in Vue (as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764825/preserve-component-state-with-vue-router)) to preserve the state of components across routes, so that when I navigate to different parts of the app the state isn't reset. That seems to work fine.

What I'd like to know is this: *is there a way to preserve the state across sites, too?* When I navigate to a different website (by clicking an external link), then hit the back button to go back to the app, I'd like the component to still preserve its state.

Is this something I can achieve in Vue at all, using either `keep-alive` or some other means?

Comment: you can save this data in `localStorage` if it isn't sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue is a client side framework. That's mean, when you leave your vue app, component will be destroyed and forget/lost everything. if you walk around in vue app its maybe possible but other way there is no way. i think, all about browser.

I agree with @Joseph you can use LocalStorage or SessionStorage, or you can call API on Vue lifecycle and fill the state every refresh or back button pressed.